# Capitalize all letters of matching regex result - null, [...], and [...,...]

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I've got a regex that returns all instances of two letter words. The results come back as either null or an array of unknown amount of items.

```
const regex_all_two_letter_words = /(\b\w{2}\b)/g;
var regexCapitalize = /[A-Z]+/g;

// inputs
const testString = [
    "j handcock",
    "je handcock",
    "jim handcock",
    "jim j handcock",
    "jim je handcock,",
    "jim jer handcock",
    "j handcock",
    "j. e, handcock",
    "j. er handcock jr",
    "jim js handcock sr",
    "jim handcock nn",
];

testString.forEach((str) => {
    var test = str.match(regex_all_two_letter_words);
    console.log(test);
});
```

**Returns**

```
null
[ 'je' ]
null
null
[ 'je' ]
null
null
null
[ 'er', 'jr' ]
[ 'js', 'sr' ]
[ 'nn' ]
```

I'm trying to capitalize both letters and replace the lowercase variants with the uppercase.

My best attempt so far:

```
    /// Inside the forEach function
    var finalStr = function (test) {
        if (test !== null) {
            var text = test.replace(regexCapitalize);
            return text;
        }
        return text;
    };
```

(Returns a bunch of functions)

Thanks

Comment: Why using a regExp to capilize both letters ? You could just use .toUpperCase(), no ?

Comment: I've been trying that but because it returns null values (cases where no two letter words were present) I think its breaking hence the if check.

Comment: Yeah well I think your if check makes sense, but then how about just doing ```var text = test.toUpperCase()```? Wouldn't be what you're trying to do ?

Comment: Yes, it still returns a list of functions. EDIT: there must be an issue with my function.

Comment: Maybe you want `test.replace(/\b\w{2}\b/g, (x) => x.toUpperCase())`?

Comment: It would help if you posted the actual code you are having an issue with instead of leaving what you are doing up to the imagination of the reader.

Comment: "capitalize both letters and replace the lowercase variants with the uppercase" <- is this the same as just saying "capitalize both letters in the two-letter word"?  or is there something else to capitalize

Comment: @Wiktor, I tried that and it only uppercased the first letter if I remember correctly...

Comment: @Tib...  I'll make a code sandbox... give me a sec

Comment: @Andrew.. no you're correct. Its the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const testStrings = [
    "j handcock",
    "je handcock",
    "jim handcock",
    "jim j handcock",
    "jim je handcock,",
    "jim jer handcock",
    "j handcock",
    "j. e, handcock",
    "j. er handcock jr",
    "jim js handcock sr",
    "jim handcock nn",
]
console.log(
  testStrings.map(s=>s.split(' ')
    .map(i=>i.replaceAll(/[^a-z]/ig,'').length===2?i.toUpperCase():i)
    .join(' '))
)
```

Comment: @MichaelMartell np. Btw I tweaked it so that "e," is not capitalized. Not sure whether you need it to be or not.

Comment: Good catch! I didn't notice!

Comment: Just studying this answer, what does the colon at the end of the map function do? Ie: "i.toUpperCase():i)"

Comment: @MichaelMartell it's part of the javascript ternary operator expression. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator It does: "if the length is exactly 2, return the uppercase version, otherwise return the original unaltered version